# <button type="submit" > behaviour different in IE and chrome : Why?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

Form Submitted Twice in IE( internet explorer version : 11.713.10586.0 ) but only once in Chrome.

```
<div id="pageButtons">
  <button type="submit" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

And the sendAction function was like :

```
function sendAction(anAction){
   document.form._action.value = anAction ;
   document.form.submit();
}
```

So since the button type is submit and also in the function sendAction I am doing submit by code, so the form was getting submitted twice concurrently.

So I changed the button HTML part to :

```
<div id="pageButtons">
      <button type="button" onClick="sendAction('submit')"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Then It worked fine in IE. Now what I am not able to understand is, if the type="submit" thing was resulting into form submission twice in IE, why was it working fine in Chrome. In chrome also, it should submit twice because button type is submit and I have also hardcode "document.form.submit()".

Can anyone give me the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Your button is continuing to execute after `sendAction()` function executes, leading to a double form submission (once as part of `sendAction()` function, and once as part of normal HTML `<form>` `<button type="submit">` behavior.

Try adding `return false` in your function:

```
function sendAction(anAction){
   document.form._action.value = anAction ;
   document.form.submit();
   return false;
}
```

And add `return` in your onClick:

```
<button type="button" onClick="return sendAction('submit');"> Submit </button>
```

This will allow `sendAction()` to trigger form submit, but then `return false` back to `onClick()` which will prevent `<button>` from its normal behavior.

Chrome is smart enough to know better as Sagar V indicates above. IE, not so smart :}

Comment: Upvoted because I don't think this deserves a downvote. Idea for why someone downvoted: The "IE is not smart" thing is opinion based.